# How to partition external USB without losing data?

Tags: installation, partitioning, external-hdd

I'm running Ubuntu 12.4 on a 8GB thumb drive. Every time I restart I lose my settings because I don't have enough room. So I want to install it on my 160GB external USB drive (FAT32). My issue is, I have over 100GB stored on it and have no where to back it up. So I want to partition only 40gig for the system install without losing any of the data already on USB.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `gparted` utility on the ubuntu live-cd to resize (shrink) your FAT32 partition. Resizing is possible without the loss of data. After you finish, you'll be having some free space for a partition for ubuntu installation.

Comment: When i tried using gparted it said to unmount the drive so i did.Then i tried to partition it and it says that ALL data will be erased.

Comment: Ok once again i figured it out and it was user error.I was trying to partition and not shrink.

Comment: Well thing thing is taking forever i realize its a big operation but the light on the thumb drive which i am running the operating system from is not blinking(not sure if it should be or not.)the light on the external drive is lit though.the progress bar is also going back and forth.

Comment: Yes, the resizing will take some time.

Comment: Yeah it took 4 hrs now im having install problems.Man this is gettin to be a pain

Comment: I figured out the install issues from a youtube video.If you are getting the no root device error format the drive with ext4 and mount as / not dos or windows just the / symbol.

Comment: So, if you succeeded in resizing and installation, accept the answer.